# Install Spinner package in Meteor 1.0

Tags: meteor

How can I install spinner package in meteor 1.0? I keep getting this message:" Package sacha:spin has no compatible build for version 2.0.4".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `meteor add sacha:spin`
meteor has package manager now,you can find packages [here](https://atmospherejs.com)